# OpenProcess() returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if program isn't elevated

Tags: delphi, winapi, process

I have successfully wrote a script to **get memory consumption** (TProcessMemoryCounters) of any process. However I need to run my program **elevated** (run as admin) in order to get these information for some system or elevated process (otherwise `OpenProcess` returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). Programs like [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) didn't need elevated mode.

My script to get memory information of a process:

```
  function GetProcessMemory(ProcID: Cardinal): Cardinal;
  var
    MemCounters: TProcessMemoryCounters;
    HProc: THandle;
  begin
    Result:= 0;
    HProc:= OpenProcess(
      PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION //or SYNCHRONIZE
      , False, ProcID);
    //HProc: 5 = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

    if GetProcessMemoryInfo(HProc, @MemCounters, SizeOf(TProcessMemoryCounters)) then
      Result :=
        MemCounters.WorkingSetSize;
  end;
```

With the following script I got memory information for all process, but still my program needs to be elevated:

```
  function EnableDebugPriv(): Boolean;
  const
    SE_DEBUG_NAME = 'SeDebugPrivilege';
  var
    HToken: NativeUInt;
    LUID: Int64;
    Tkp: TTokenPrivileges;
    AA: Cardinal;
  begin
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess,
      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY,
      HToken
    );

    LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, SE_DEBUG_NAME, LUID);

    Tkp.PrivilegeCount:= 1;
    Tkp.Privileges[0].Luid:= LUID;
    Tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes:= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(HToken, False, Tkp, SizeOf(Tkp), nil, AA);

    CloseHandle(HToken);
  end;
```

**Q:** How to make my script get memory information of all process (include systems) without elevated mode?

Comment: no way. you really need be elevated for open all processes, even with only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`

Comment: What makes you think you can do this without elevation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I've already state that Process Explorer didn't need elevated mode. Actually I didn't care about elevated or not, I really don't want to show that UAC yes/no dialog.

Comment: As far as I know Process explorer is using [Process Status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/windows/win32/psapi/process-status-helper) for checking status pf running programs. You can find more information regarding this matter in SO question [How can I get other processes' information with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616408/3636228)

Answer (score 2):

To use `GetProcessMemoryInfo()`, you must specify the `PROCESS_VM_READ` access right as well, as stated by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo):

> *Process*
>
> A handle to the process. The handle must have the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access right **and the `PROCESS_VM_READ` access right**. For more information, see Process Security and Access Rights.
>
> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The handle must have the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` **and `PROCESS_VM_READ`** access rights.

You are also leaking the handle if it were able to be opened successfully.

Try this instead:

```pascal
function GetProcessMemory(ProcID: DWORD): DWORD;
var
  MemCounters: TProcessMemoryCounters;
  HProc: THandle;
begin
  Result := 0;
  HProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, ProcID);
  if HProc <> 0 then
  begin
    if GetProcessMemoryInfo(HProc, @MemCounters, SizeOf(TProcessMemoryCounters)) then
      Result := MemCounters.WorkingSetSize;
    CloseHandle(HProc);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and leak problem, you right about documentation, but I didn't have problem without it. With `PROCESS_VM_READ` my program can't get mem info for elevated process and all system process (when my program itself isn't elevated). When my program elevated I can't get mem info only for few system process.

Comment: @SAMPro that makes sense. You can't access memory for a process that is running in a higher integrity level than your process's integrity level. The only way to get complete unrestricted access to the system is to run your code in a background service as the `SYSTEM` user. You could do the memory query from there, and use IPC to send the info to a non-elevated front-end process for display